# Ajax request in YouTube API browser-based upload

Tags: ajax, youtube-api

I'd like to upload a YouTube video using ajax requests. The following script is used to create a form in order to upload a video to YouTube:

```
    function createUploadForm($videoTitle, $videoDescription, $videoCategory, $videoTags,     $nextUrl = null)
{
    $httpClient = getAuthSubHttpClient();
    $youTubeService = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient);
    $newVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

    $newVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($videoTitle);
    $newVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($videoDescription);

    //make sure first character in category is capitalized
    $videoCategory = strtoupper(substr($videoCategory, 0, 1))
        . substr($videoCategory, 1);
    $newVideoEntry->setVideoCategory($videoCategory);

    // convert videoTags from whitespace separated into comma separated
    $videoTagsArray = explode(' ', trim($videoTags));
    $newVideoEntry->setVideoTags(implode(', ', $videoTagsArray));

    $tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
    try {
        $tokenArray = $youTubeService->getFormUploadToken($newVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
        if (loggingEnabled()) {
            logMessage($httpClient->getLastRequest(), 'request');
            logMessage($httpClient->getLastResponse()->getBody(), 'response');
        }
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
        print 'ERROR ' . $httpException->getMessage()
            . ' HTTP details<br /><textarea cols="100" rows="20">'
            . $httpException->getRawResponseBody()
            . '</textarea><br />'
            . '<a href="session_details.php">'
            . 'click here to view details of last request</a><br />';
        return;
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        print 'ERROR - Could not retrieve token for syndicated upload. '
            . $e->getMessage()
            . '<br /><a href="session_details.php">'
            . 'click here to view details of last request</a><br />';
        return;
    }

    $tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
    $postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];

    // place to redirect user after upload
    if (!$nextUrl) {
        $nextUrl = $_SESSION['homeUrl'];
    }

    print <<< END
        <br /><form id="ajaxform" action="${postUrl}?nexturl=${nextUrl}"
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="file" type="file"/>
        <input name="token" type="hidden" value="${tokenValue}"/>
        <input value="Upload Video File" type="submit" />
        </form>
END;
}
```

At the end, a form is created using `action="${postUrl}?nexturl=${nextUrl}` which tells to YouTube to redirect the browser after the uploading has been completed. When the user is redirected, to `nextUrl`, two variables are passed with the URL (the status of the uploaded video and an ID for that video). I don't want a page reload but it seems that `nextUrl` is mandatory. Furthermore, I want to be able to get that ID for further use.

Is it possible to change the behavior of that automatic redirection and to pass those values in any other way?

Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution for something like this.