# Is it possible to upload a video to Youtube without a redirect?

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube

The Youtube API, within the Zend Framework, specifies that I can upload a video to Youtube through a form using browser-based uploading. However, such a form requires a postback page defined in the "nexturl" parameter of the query string.

I'm attempting to modify Gravity Forms (a Wordpress plugin) so that I can upload a video to Youtube as an inline function of a form submission. This means that I can't set my form action to point to Youtube; it has to point to native Gravity Forms support.

Is there any way to upload a video to Youtube without having to use this redirect? If not, the only way that I would be able to make this work would be to open a new window and perform the upload there (which isn't ideal).

If anyone has any experience with this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What if you did it in an `IFRAME` embedded onto your page?

Comment: I was considering doing it this way (or even in a new window), but I believe that it would still require user input (I've been reading more about the API). For browser-based uploads, Youtube takes the metadata of the video first and then sends back a form for the user to upload the actual video content. I'm trying to avoid use input for this area, as it could break my form submission.

Comment: What if you then used AJAX to `POST` the metadata and update your page with the form that YouTube replies with?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6317781/677526. The main problem with this is that I don't want users to have to input anything into that form that Youtube sends back, and I also nee to get my POST data from my form. One requirement is that I can't complete form submission until this step complete. I've been thinking about manipulating query strings directly, maybe using cURL or something, but I'd have to figure out whether this is even a possibility.